# django authenticate two registration form

Tags: django, registration

I am making a system where I want to authenticate two forms. Like there will be two users one might be job provider and another one will be job seeker. I want them both to register. There will be different form for both the users. How can I authenticate them and register them ? Any help. I am willing to use django-registration for registration system. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Registration and authentication are like two different tasks...

Comment: I want both of them to register and login...

Comment: Do it sequentially (otherwise you'll need to deal with error handling when one person forgets to enter their password etc.).

Comment: try to use Form wizard                                                https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/ to handle more then 1 form